# My warning label is not showing on invalid input

Tags: javascript, css, label, hidden

I don't want to use JQuery (yet), so I'm trying to find an alternative solution.
I have written a from with a working validation function. Now I wan to add a function that edits a label to be shown on invalid input. My css code is like this:

```
#invalidInputHidden{
    display:none;
    color:#FF0000;
}
.error{
    display:block;
}
```

So the alerting text is hidden at first. In my JavaScript I add a class to the label, which should make it visible again. I put this in the validation function:

```
invalidInputHidden.className += " error";
```

Yet this doesn't happen. Is it because of the fact that an id has priority over a class, so it will always have "display:none;" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is it because of the fact that an id has priority over a class"*

Yep.

> *"...so it will always have `display:none;`?"*

Well, not *always.* One way to get around the usual specificity rules is using [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception):

```
.error{
    display:block !important;
}
```

It's not generally considered good practice, indeed the MDN link I provided above advises against it, but personally I don't mind it in your case where your `.error` class likely is supposed to be the most important style rule when applied.

Comment: Ah okay, great. I'll try it with an !important statement then :)